# Does this Go method "allocate new memory"?

Tags: go, memory-management

(I'm learning Go using Donovan and Kernighan's [*The Go Programming Language*](https://www.gopl.io). The answer to this will probably be painfully obvious to others, but I'm stumped and not sure where to begin.)

As an exercise in *GOPL*, the authors ask the reader to modify their `reverse` program (which reverses a slice of `int`s in place)  "to reverse the characters of a `[]byte` slice that represents a UTF-8 encoded string, in place" (93). They add: "Can you do it without allocating new memory?"

In a nutshell, I want to ask whether the following allocates new memory. I think that it doesn't, based on the outcome of the print statements, but I'm not sure. Another way to put my confusion is this: if the `reverse` method reverses *in place*, I would expect it *not* to allocate new memory. So, I'm assuming that I must be missing something because they ask for the method to work in place and then *add* the challenge of not allocating new memory. Are they nudging me to avoid something I've done? Is there some extra trick here worth knowing about memory allocation (in Go or in general)?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    phrase := "Hello, 世界!"
    fmt.Printf("Before reverse:\tmemory address %p => phrase: %s\n", &phrase, phrase)
    phrase = string(reverseByRune([]byte(phrase)))
    fmt.Printf("After reverse:\tmemory address %p => phrase: %s\n", &phrase, phrase)
}

func reverseByRune(b []byte) []byte {
    for i := 0; i < len(b); {
        _, size := utf8.DecodeRune(b[i:])
        reverse(b[i : i+size])
        i += size
    }
    reverse(b)
    return b
}

func reverse(b []byte) []byte {
    for i, j := 0, len(b)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        b[i], b[j] = b[j], b[i]
    }
    return b
}
```

Here it is on the Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Qn7nYXLGoQn.

PS I can only upvote and accept once, but if anyone wants extra thanks, I'd love any links about memory allocation (especially in Go).

Comment: It's not defined whether it allocates memory or not. Technically I would expect this usage of the function to require allocations, because converting from a string to a slice or slice to a string must make a copy, however that could technically be optimized out in some cases. Printing the address of your string variable doesn't show anything.

Comment: You can also check actual allocated memory by writing a simple benchmark and using `-benchmem`

Comment: I had the same thought about the conversions, but those happen outside of the function itself, and I wasn't sure whether they were specifying no memory allocation *in the function*. I wrote the string as a `string` because it's easier than typing a `[]byte` slice, but in theory we could leave the string conversion out altogether.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for the tips. My larger question remains: do you have a sense of what they were trying to nudge the reader towards (or away from)? Set aside the conversions (I think?): what should the function do or not do to avoid unnecessary memory allocation? Why would an in-place swapping function on a slice ever need to allocate new memory?

Comment: By "without allocating new memory" they just mean "don't allocate a new slice", i.e. don't use `make` and don't `append` to the capacity of the slice.

Comment: I think the prompt is fairly vague; not allocating *any* memory is impossible, but this doesn't allocate a new slice, and *probably* doesn't allocate on the heap at all.

Comment: Also, part of your confusion may be that when something talks about "allocation" in Go, it invariably means "heap allocation" as opposed to stack.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Probably the implementation in the question also does not allocate memory on the heap, but the suggested modification still should be a tiny little bit more efficient. I originally thought the code in the question is from the book and has memory allocations that I can't check due to lack of local compiler.

Here is an implementation that I believe should be without memory allocation.

https://play.golang.org/p/N4mkYoiIHvn

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    phrase := "Hello, 世界!"
    fmt.Printf("Before reverse:\tmemory address %p => phrase: %s\n", &phrase, phrase)
    phrase = string(reverseByRune([]byte(phrase)))
    fmt.Printf("After reverse:\tmemory address %p => phrase: %s\n", &phrase, phrase)
}

func reverseByRune(b []byte) []byte {
    reverse := func (i, j int) {
        for ; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
            b[i], b[j] = b[j], b[i]
        }
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(b); {
        _, size := utf8.DecodeRune(b[i:])
        reverse(i, i+size-1)
        i += size
    }
    reverse(0, len(b)-1)
    return b
}
```

The original implementation of `reverse()` needs memory to create the `b []byte` slice and also unnecessarily returns a value. Though theoretically that could be optimized by removing `return` from `reverse`. Then a compiler can "guess" nobody can keep a pointer to the slice and can make sure the slice is created on stack instead of the heap. But this is just theoretical speculation-I'm not sure if Go's compiler is that smart.

The suggested implementation does same as the original but within the original slice.

When we talk about "no memory allocation," we usually mean what happens within a function, in this case the `reverseByRune()`. Local variables allocated on stack like `i` & `j` does not count as they are cheap.

And here is what probably would be the most efficient implementation for given approach:

https://play.golang.org/p/YOOSZjIWKZ_r

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    phrase := []byte("Hello, 世界!")
    fmt.Printf("Before reverse:\tmemory address %p => phrase: %s\n", &phrase, string(phrase))
    reverseByRune(phrase)
    fmt.Printf("After reverse:\tmemory address %p => phrase: %s\n", &phrase, string(phrase))
}

func reverseByRune(b []byte) {
    for i := 0; i < len(b); {
        _, size := utf8.DecodeRune(b[i:])
        for k, p := i, i+size-1; k < p; k, p = k+1, p-1 {
            b[k], b[p] = b[p], b[k]
        }
        i += size
    }
    for i, j := 0, len(b)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        b[i], b[j] = b[j], b[i]
    }
}
```

But that is overkill!

Comment: I was editing answer and it overwritten your good correction - race condition in action!

Comment: This is equivalent to the original, which also does not create a new slice

Comment: This `reverse(b[i : i+size])` creates a new slice (though pointing to existing array).

Comment: Yes, but that value is copied back in your version too via the return statement. Run this in a benchmark and you’ll see 0 allocations, because “allocations” is generally meant to mean heap.

Comment: Agree, most probably authors implementation also does not allocate. I do not have Go on current laptop so can't check - will update the answer.